# How to build a QTextDocument with QTextBlocks from AST and maintain relation

Tags: python, qt, abstract-syntax-tree, pyside6, qtextdocument

I wrote a lexer and parser which outputs an AST of nodes with parent and child elements (see https://github.com/oohlaf/watchadoin/tree/main/src/watchadoin).

Now I want to create a GUI in QT with PySide6 and make a QTextEdit widget. Now I understand from https://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-5.7/richtext-structure.html it uses a QTextDocument as underlying document object with QTextBlocks and QTextFragmnents.

I could map the AST nodes to those elements, for example a textblock for a single line consisting of text fragments. But I don't see methods to instantiate those classes and set the contents. Should I construct that hierarchy from the AST using a visitor operating on a TextCursor? But how does one keep those trees in sync?

How do code editors do this? Could not find any relevant references on Google.

Comment: Advanced code editors don't use the basic QTextEdit, as its default QTextDocument interface is not intended for that kind of interaction. First of all, is that document intended to be editable, or only for displaying purposes? In the second case, you might consider not using a text editor at all, and possibly implement visualization using the [Graphics View framework](//doc.qt.io/qt-5/graphicsview.html), otherwise you will probably need to create your own [QAbstractTextDocumentLayout](//doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextdocument.html#documentLayout) (which is *very* complex).

Comment: You have to consider that the default document layout is not intended for that level of "inspection" (which is only available internally at the lower level, within the document layout object, and that's because the general purpose of QTextDocument is to read and write *text*, not directly manipulate its hierarchicaly structure), so if you need to keep in sync the text *and* the tree of nodes, you must be able to directly access those elements and keep persistent references of the object structure. Maybe there could be some "hope" with QScintilla?

Comment: I do intent to allow the document to be edited, not just viewing. Using plain text is ok, as the input language is plain text and the lexer/parser I created is able to validate if the input is correct or not. As there is nesting in the input, I'd like folding per indent level.

So I suppose I could just make it one big textblock with all the contents and forget about keeping it in sync. Just reparse on changes.

Comment: Thanks for the hints above @musicamante. I managed to create a first attempt on a GUI. Used a QPlainTextEdit with a QSyntaxHighlighter in which I was able to reuse my tokenizer for highlighting syntax.